# Email Message Indentation error in G-mail when sent from my E-mail program

Tags: .net, email, gmail, indentation, auto-indent

I'm encountering an issue with a Google product or service and would appreciate your assistance. Here are the details:
Product/Service: Gmail

Description of the issue:
I am using an email application coded in VB.NET for sending and receiving emails. It is connected to a Gmail account, i.e., the emails are sent and received through Gmail. The logic used is that the emails are composed in a MS Word document (.doc format), which is then sent in HTML format.

When I send mail from the program, I see that an indentation is created when the mail is received by a Gmail user only. (as mentioned in the attached screenshot). Hotmail works fine; also, when the user saves the same email in Gmail as an ‘.EML’ file and opens it in Microsoft Mail, Outlook and Thunderbird, there are no indentations, and the recipient is able to view the email properly.
I would like to know whether there are any tags being used in our email application that are not being supported by Gmail.
Here is snippet I use to send email using word and outlook program

```
If WordOpen = True Then
olkMsg = wrdDoc.MailEnvelope.Item
ElseIf (InStrRev(imgpaths, ".html", , CompareMethod.Text) = Len(imgpaths) - 4) Then
Try
    ValidBodyFile = True
    OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    olkMsg = OutlookApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
    olkMsg.HTMLBody = File.ReadAllText(imgpaths)
Catch ex As System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
    OutlookApp = Nothing
    Continue For
End Try
End If
```

[Screenshot of the G-mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/706wx.png)

[Screen shot of Microsoft Mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qt1gd.png)